# Merge Object from Different Services in Angular

Tags: angular, object, merge

I want to marge different object come from different services.

My services like that:

```
  getEndPoint(base): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/latest?access_key=' + this.apiKey + '&base=' + base).pipe(
      retry(1)
    );
  }

  getLastPoint(base): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/2019-09-17?access_key=' + this.apiKey + '&base=' + base).pipe(
      retry(1)
    );
  }
```

My component like that:

```
getSymbolDetail(base: string): void {

    this.symbolService.getEndPoint(base).subscribe( data => {
      this.symbolEndPoint = data;
    });

    this.symbolService.getLastPoint(base).subscribe(data => {
      this.symbolLastDayPoint = data.rates.EUR;
      console.log(this.symbolEndPoint);
    });
  }
```

My mistake is, symbolEndPoint could be old data when I run the same component twice. So how I can merge two object (symbolEndPoint and symbolLastDayPoint)?

Comment: Have you tried this approach? https://riptutorial.com/rxjs/example/28035/sending-multiple-sequential-http-requests

Comment: I don't know anything approach. I will try. Thank you Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by [this article](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61).

I changed my service like this.

```
getDetail(base): Observable<any> {
let getSymbols = this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/symbols?access_key=' + this.apiKey);
let getEndPoint = this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/latest?access_key=' + this.apiKey + '&base=' + base);
let getLastPoint = this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/2019-09-17?access_key=' + this.apiKey + '&base=' + base);
return forkJoin([getSymbols, getEndPoint, getLastPoint]);};
```

and my component:

```
getSymbolDetail(base: string): void {
this.symbolService.getDetail(base).subscribe(data => {
  this.symbolName = data[0].symbols[base];
  this.symbolEndPoint = data[1].rates.EUR;
  this.symbolLastDayPoint = data[2].rates.EUR;
  this.symbolDailyChange = (this.symbolEndPoint - this.symbolLastDayPoint).toString().substring(0, 8);
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are related you can use **object.assign**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Else you can use a **tuple**

https://codingblast.com/typescript-tuples/